# Getting an error when trying to download a Python package on Linux

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to use the 'bleak' package on a raspberry bi to connect to Bluetooth Low Energy peripherals.
When I use the command `pip install bleak` i get the error :

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dbus-next; platform_system == "Linux" (from bleak) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for dbus-next; platform_system ++ "Linux" (from bleak)`

It is stated on [their website](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak) that they do support Linux platforms.

I tried to download the package on my Macbook where it installed wihtout any problems.

Any help for what that error message means exactly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may be running into an issue where the precompiled package is not available/compatible with the Pi's ARM processor, whose instruction set is different from Intel/AMD/etc.'s `x86_64` - recompiling from source on the pi itself should to the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're using a wrong version of pip , **try** `pip3 install bleak`. if it didn't work edit your post with the outputs of these commands:

```sh
which python
which pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue... followed the advice from Jonathan, and got similar errors:

```
No local packages or working download links found for dbus-next; platform_system == "Linux"
error: Could not find suitable distrbuiton for Requirement.parse('dbus-next; platform_system == "Linux"')
```

I followed the same procedure to clone and intstall `python-dbus-next`, and this appears to have cleared up the issue.

https://github.com/altdesktop/python-dbus-next

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing from the sources ([Reference](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html))

To paraphrase the given link:

Clone from GitHub: `$ git clone git://github.com/hbldh/bleak` 
Access the repo: `$ cd ~/bleak` (assuming you cloned at your root) 
Install the source: `$ python setup.py install`